# scanf for getting a complete line

Tags: c, input

```
char a[100];
scanf(" %[^\n]s\n",a);
```

I know that the above code will take the whole data still you get '\n'
but how exactly the square braces and a xor symbol tell this I am unable to understand how it works.

Any one who exactly know how the square braces and the xor in a `scanf()` mean?

Comment: C++ or C? In C++, you would not use such code because you have `std::string` and `std::getline`.

Comment: The `"s"` in `scanf(" %[^\n]s\n",a);` serves no useful purpose.

Comment: @Christian Hackl  C++ or C? `scanf()` should not be used in either C++ or C.  So maybe both tags should be removed?

Answer (score 1):

> `[` Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from a set of expected 
>   characters (the scanset) ...
>
> ... The characters between the brackets (the scanlist) compose the scanset, unless the character after the left bracket is a circumflex (^), in which case the scanset contains all characters that do not appear in the scanlist between the circumflex and the right bracket. ... C11dr §7.21.6.2 12

To read a line using `scanf()`, use the following.  Notice there is no `"s"` in the format.

```
char a[100];

// Read up to 99 character that are not \n
switch(scanf("%99[^\n]", a)) {
  // some text was read - the usual path
  case 1: break;
  // Nothing read, first char was \n
  case 0: a[0] = 0; break;
  // stdin is closed, no more input or input error
  case EOF: return;
}

// Now read and discard rest of line which is _usually_ just a \n
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
  ;
}
```

---

Using `scanf()` to read a line does not make for robust C code.
Recommend to use `fgets()` and almost never use `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `[ ]` = set of scan-able characters, means set of characters including these braces are only scan-able by `scanf()`.`
2. `^` = this sign says `scanf()` may scan every characters without those set after this sign.

   i.e. `char a[100];
   scanf(" %[^\n]s\n", &a);` means we scan everything without new-line character.

Comment: The `"s"` in `scanf(" %[^\n]s\n",a);` serves no useful purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `[ ]`.  This is a bit like the character class you see in regex.

`^` means not, so `[^\n]` means not newline.

So `[^\n]` means grab anything that is not a newline.  If the line consists of more than just a newline then it grabs everything up to the `\n`.

You have a space before the `%[^\n]` - that seems to have no effect - using Visual Studio 2013 anyway.

I don't understand what the `s` is doing there?  A mistake?

If you had:

```
scanf("%s", a);
```

and entered the string: `querty keyboard`, then `a` would be: `querty`.  It grabs up to any whitespace.  But serves no purpose in your format string as it is.

You also don't need the 2<sup>nd</sup> `\n` in the format string.

Comment: Note: "space before the %[^\n]" --> the  `" "` directs `scanf()` to scan and discard optional white-spaces like `' '` and `'\n'`.